# handling array inputs from views in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller

In my inventory application one of my view sends multiple products information in the form off array and some plain inputs to the controller which is then passed to the model for storage in multiple database tables named orders and product. I know how to handle plain inputs by passing them in array to model function.

```
function add_record($data);
```

but I want to know how to handle the array inputs along simple inputs in controller to send them to the model?

**in my view:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="vendor" id="vendor">
   <option value="">Place order to</option>
   <?php foreach ($vendors as $val=>$vendor) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $val; ?>"><?php echo $vendor;?></option>
   <?php };?>
</select>
<table>
   <tbody class="detail">
      <tr>
         <td class="no">1</td>
         <td>
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control productname" name="productname[]"> -->
            <select class="form-control productname" name="productname[]">
               <option value="">Select Product</option>
               <?php foreach($products as $val => $product){ ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $val;?>"><?php echo $product;?></option>
               <?php } ?>
            </select>
         </td>
```

and on submit I am passing them to a controller `addorder/createOrder` i.e create order function of addorder controller.

Comment: from your code, i can see only one set of order and product...

Comment: rest of them are dynamically added as one can add as many product as they needed so that is why I pushed them into an array.You can assume there  is an array and multiple products into it.

Comment: you will have vendor only once??

Comment: yes it only once and multiple products

Comment: now, for one vendor, multiple products??

Comment: yes there is one vendor and multiple product inputs in array

Comment: how will u store the products?? can u tel me ...

Comment: this is the var dump so far
Array ( 
 [vendor] => 1 
 [ordernumber] => abc123 
 [productname] => Array ( 
  [0] => 7 
  [1] => 8 
  ) 
 [quantity] => Array ( 
  [0] => 23 
  [1] => 22 
  ) 
 [price] => Array ( 
   [0] => 2 
   [1] => 2 
   ) 
 [subtotal] => Array ( 
  [0] => 46 
  [1] => 44 
 ) 
 [save] => Save Record 
)

Comment: this is what I have carried out in controller and I want to insert vendor and order number to order table and get its id and then I wan to add order id and products to order details table.

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing the values in different rows, use this

```
foreach($this->input->post("productname") as $row) {
    $productId = $row;
    // insert product id to database
}
```

If you want to store using comma(`,`) separated, use this

```
$priductId = implode(",",$this->input->post("productname"));
    // insert product id's to database
```

To get back product id's use

```
explode(",",$variabl from database);// will get array
```

You can also use `json_encode()` and store in json format

```
$priductId = json_encode($this->input->post("productname"));
    // insert product id's to database
```

To get back product id's use

```
json_decode($variabl from database);// will get array
```